# Measures/KPIs based on conditional/filtered counts in SSAS

Tags: ssas, mdx

I'm trying to work out how to define some of the KPI's.
If I may give an example:

**Fact Table**
ReferenceNo
CountofReferenceNo (Measure)

**Dimension**
ReferenceNumber
Status
Type

So let's say that one of our official KPI's is a count of reference numbers of a certain type ie type = 'generic'. Is it possible to use an expression to define a KPI Value that is a measure with an added filter? Or would this need to be created as an additional measure? If a measure, then I cannot work out how to add custom calculated measure, nor how to write it if I could!

The equivalent SQL would be:

```
SELECT COUNT(ReferenceNo)
FROM FactTable INNER JOIN
Dimension ON FactTable.ReferenceNo = Dimension.ReferenceNo
WHERE Dimension.Type = 'generic'
```

If I could work out this one, then most of our KPI's are similar and are based on counts so I should hopefully be able to go on and work out the rest.

Comment: what `mdx` have you tried? are you trying to develop a statement to add into the cube script? or are you trying to add a measure to a report - if so will the report be in SSRS, xl ..?

Comment: Did my answer help you out at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sql in `mdx` would be something like:

```
SELECT 
   [Measures].[CountofReferenceNo] ON 0 
FROM [YourCube] 
WHERE [DimensionType].[generic];
```

Or you can create a `tuple` in a custom measure inside a `WITH` clause:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[CountofReferenceNo_Generic] AS
(
 [Measures].[CountofReferenceNo]
 ,[DimensionType].[generic]
)
SELECT 
   [Measures].[CountofReferenceNo_Generic] ON 0 
FROM [YourCube];
```